# How to assign value of field of one model to field of another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Say, I have a view function that creates a `Vacancy` object on saving the form, and it has the field `company` that, if the form is valid, has to be assigned with value of field `name`, that is on the other model named `EmployerProfile`, how can I do that? I have `company` as a foreign key on my model.

**My models**

```
class EmployerProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    description = models.TextField()
    username = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Vacancy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    competences = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    salary = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 10)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(EmployerProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

**My view**

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def vacancyAddView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VacancyAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = VacancyAddForm()
    context = {
        'form':form
    }

    return render(request, "addVacancy.html", context)
```

**My form**

```
class VacancyAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vacancy
        fields = [
            'name',
            'competences',
            'description',
            'salary',
        ]
```

P.S. I have tried adding this piece of code to my view, rigth after `form.is_valid():`

```
obj = EmployerProfile.objects.get(username = request.user)
form.instance.company = obj.name
```

but it didn't work, it returned the `ValueError` with text `"Vacancy.company" must be a "EmployerProfile" instance.`

P.P.S. I also tried to override the `save` method in my model like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.company = self.EmployerProfile.name
    super(Vacancy, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want. Your Vacancy  model defines company as a foreign key, but you're trying to set it as a string.

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(EmployerProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

However, here's what your view should change to be to work with your models as you've defined them currently.

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def vacancyAddView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VacancyAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Set the company
            form.instance.company = request.user.employerprofile
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = VacancyAddForm()
    context = {
        'form':form
    }

    return render(request, "addVacancy.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue here is that you can't set a ForeignKey field to be a string. If you want the user to be able to set the Company from the form, you have a couple of choices. One is to take what you have now in the form and use it to filter, e.g. something like:

```
company = EmployerProfile.objects.filter(name__iexact=form.cleaned_data['company'])
form.instance.company = company
```

Another would be to change the form so that instead of a text input, `company` is a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), or a regular ChoiceField populated with the company choices available to the user.

In either case the end goal will be to ensure that the company field contains a foreign key to an EmployerProfile object, rather than the string name of a company.