# How to access a field through a sub table Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I Have a table `Product` and a table `Variation`, `Variation` has `ManyToOne` relation i.e. `ForeignKey` with the table.

I want only first `object` of `Variation`, so that I can render it fields, which I want.

The way I am currently implementing to call the first object in html page:

> {{item.variation.price_set.first}}
>
> `Note:` {{item}} is my product object or instance.

Html file:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for item in TopItems %}
        {% if item.image %}
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto m-auto" src="{{item.image.url}}" alt="{{item.name}}">
                <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                <p>{{item.variation.price_set.first}}</p>
                <p>{{item.variation_set.first}}</p>
                {% if item.variation.promotion_price_set.first%}
                <h2 class="text-primary">
                    {{item.variation.promotion_price}}
                </h2>
                <h2 class="text-primary">
                    {{item.variation.price}}
                </h2>
                {% else %}
                <h2 class="text-primary">
                    {{item.variation.price}}
                </h2>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor%}
</div>
```

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    long_description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = ResizedImageField(
        size=[550, 300], quality=70, upload_to='product_images/%Y/%m/%d')
    #image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/%Y/%m/%d')
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True, always_update=False,
                         populate_from="name")
    top_item = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name="product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        SubCategory, related_name="sub", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    available = AvailableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("name",)  # vai ser ordenado pelo nome não o ID

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})



class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    promotion_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    availableVariation = AvailableManagerVariation()
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or self.product.name
```

Views.py, the below method is passing all records to the template.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context["TopItems"]= Product.objects.filter(top_item=True)
```

So, How can I get only first record of `variaton`, so that I can show respective prices?

Comment: Its not very clear and understandable to me, but i think you are asking how can I display `price` through my `Product` model's instance, so it will be `{{item.variation.price}}`.

Comment: It doesn't work. it's a 1 to N table, there's  a Product, and each Product has an N numbers  of Variations. I want to get the  Price of the first Variation

------Note: even if I did to display all variation prices, it didnt work

Comment: Check this question & answer seems to be similar to your case [how-to-assign-value-of-field-of-one-model-to-field-of-another-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974332/how-to-assign-value-of-field-of-one-model-to-field-of-another-model)

Comment: @Vignesh this question you sent me, it's a total different thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nested` loops, for accessing only first `promotion price as well as price` in the following way:

This is a minimal reproducible example, as not able to understand your design.

```html
{% for item in TopItems %}

<div>
    <p> {{item.name}} </p>
    <p>{{forloop.counter}}st variation</p>

    {% for variation in item.variation_set.all  %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 < 1 %}
        <p>First variation price of  - {{variation.price}}</p> 
        {% comment  %}It will give only first price {% endcomment %}
        <p>First variation promotion price - {{variation.promotion_price}}</p>
        {% comment  %}It will give only first promotion price{% endcomment %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<br>
{%endfor%}
```

> `Note:` There must be a space between `template` tags, as so write it as `{% endif %}` not `{%endif%}`, similarly for `{% endfor %}`  not `{%endfor%}`.
>
> `Note:` It will be better, if you pass your context keys in `snake_case` rather than `PascalCase`, so it can be passed as `top_items` rather than `TopItems`.